# Checkbox returns true even when unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am having trouble with an if-statement. In this statement i want to check if a checkbox is checked true (or isSelected) then it shall proceed with the instruction to disable a textarea. This part is working fine. But unfortunately if the checkbox is unchecked it still disabling the textarea, but it shouldn't. It should leave the textarea enabled.

```
function auswahl_bestaetigen(){

    tweet = document.getElementById("chk_tweet")
    twitter = document.getElementById("twitter")

    if (tweet.isSelected = true)
                twitter.disabled = true
    else if (tweet.isSelected = false) 
                twitter.disabled = false    
}
```

i hope someone can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `if (tweet.isSelected = true)` should be `if (tweet.isSelected)`. `=` means assignment. Also, this is not Java.

Comment: There is also no isSelected property

Comment: The question is not very clear altogether. It is implied that we're talking about JavaScript and HTML DOM but it would be better to be explicit. The HTML example would help too. Ideally, you'd present a working or broken test on some of the on-line snippet sites like https://jsfiddle.net/ . To the topic itself, I'll recommend W3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_checkbox.asp as the question has been answered pretty much. Note, the down-vote was not mine. You get down votes when the quality of your question is in trouble.

Comment: Downvoting questions like this is just silly. Not getting an answer should be a good enough indication that the question is posted in the wrong format or in the wrong place. I don't get why some people find it necessary to downvote as on top of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property to test whether an `<input type="checkbox">` is checked is called `checked`. So your code should be:

```
if (tweet.checked) {
  twitter.disabled = true
} else {
  twitter.disabled = false
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
twitter.disabled = tweet.checked
```

Here's a simple demo:

```js
var tweet = document.getElementById('chk_tweet')
var twitter = document.getElementById('twitter')
tweet.addEventListener('change', function () {
  twitter.disabled = tweet.checked
});
```

```css
#twitter[disabled] {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<input id="chk_tweet" type="checkbox" />

<textarea id="twitter"></textarea>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/m4oda3zy/